# How to draw guide lines /w bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I draw following plot with `bokeh.plotting.Figure.line`.
How I can add vertical guideline to emphasize a point of Feb/14 ?

[image]

Here's another plot. This is `bokeh.charts.Bar`.
I'd like to add horizontal guideline to emphasize a point of 50. I searched [bokeh doc](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference.html) but have no luck to find relevant API reference. It would be appreciate someone address me about this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a vertical line to a simple line chart by creating a new set of data that corresponded to the vertical line I wanted to create.

```
from datetime import *
x = [date(2001,1,1), date(2002,1,1),date(2003,1,1), date(2004,1,1),
        date(2005,1,1), date(2006,1,1),date(2007,1,1), date(2008,1,1),
        date(2009,1,1), date(2010,1,1),date(2011,1,1)]
y = [0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 9, 15, 18, 19, 25, 28]
output_file("lines.html", title="line plot example")
p = figure(title="simple line example",x_axis_type = "datetime")
p.line(x, y)
a = [min(y),max(y)]
b = [date(2009,1,1),date(2009,1,1)]
p.line(b, a ,line_color="red")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly easily with the ray glyph in bokeh.  If you set the angle to be 1.57079633 (90 degrees in radians) you'll get a vertical ray.  Just update the x value to be where you want the line and the length to be the height of your x axis.

```
p.ray(x=.5, y=0, length=1, angle=1.57079633, color='black')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the new `BoxAnnotation` (new as of Bokeh 0.9.3) with zero width or height to do this, with slightly better effect:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#box-annotations

It's probably worth adding a `LineAnnotation` as well, I'll make an issue for it.